# Javax Mail - can't connect to email server

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

i have follwing code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.pop3.host", "pop.1und1.de");
    props.put("mail.pop3.user", "xxxx");
    // Start SSL connection
    props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory", 995);
    props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.pop3.port", 995);

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxx", "xxxx");
        }
    });

    try {

        Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect("pop.1und1.de", "xxxx", "xxxx");

        Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");

[...]
```

I want to connect to an '1und1' Server. But it dosen't.I can't connect to my email server.

Here's the error:

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: EOF on socket  at
>   com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:209)   at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)  at
>   de.beans.webservice.KoordinationsBean.downloadEmailAttachments(KoordinationsBean.java:990)
>     at
>   de.beans.webservice.KoordinationsBean.emailsLesen(KoordinationsBean.java:278)
>     at
>   de.beans.webservice.KoordinationsBean.starteTransition(KoordinationsBean.java:243)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)  at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Paste the error which you are getting here.

Comment: Try replace `Store store = session.getStore("pop3");` with `Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");`

Comment: Avihoo Mamka: It works. But why 'pop3s'? I thought 'pop3' would be the right one

Comment: @user3515460 Because pop3s means pop3 with SSL.

Comment: Note that if you use "pop3", all the property names need to be changed from `mail.pop3.*` to `mail.pop3s.*`.  And you can [get rid of the socket factory properties](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).